# Join lists to export as csv

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to join two lists and export as csv, but when the csv is built, it's all messed up with spaces that I don't know the origin of and with the first line strangely duplicated as you can see in the attached image.

```
import csv

amazondata = [{'amzlink': 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B084ZZ7VY3', 'asin': 'B084ZZ7VY3', 'url': 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=712145360504&s=review-rank', 'title': '100% Non-GMO Berberine HCL Complex Supplement - Supports Gut, Heart, and Immune System Health- Harvested in The Himalayas, Helps Regulate Blood Sugar & Cholesterol, 100% Free of Additives & Allergens', 'price': '$14.95', 'image': 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/W/IMAGERENDERING_521856-T2/images/I/81D1P4QqLfL._AC_SX425_.jpg', 'rank': 'Best Sellers Rank: #194,130 in Health & Household (See Top 100 in Health & Household)\n#6,896 in Blended Vitamin & Mineral Supplements', 'rating': '4.7 out of 5'}, {'amzlink': 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000NRTWS6', 'asin': 'B000NRTWS6', 'url': 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=753950000698&s=review-rank'}, {'amzlink': 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07XM9P4C4', 'asin': 'B07XM9P4C4', 'url': 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=753950005266&s=review-rank'}, {'amzlink': 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08KJ1VQJD', 'asin': 'B08KJ1VQJD', 'url': 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=753950005242&s=review-rank'}, {'amzlink': 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B005P0VD4W', 'asin': 'B005P0VD4W', 'url': 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=043292560180&s=review-rank'}, {'amzlink': 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B008FCJTES', 'asin': 'B008FCJTES', 'url': 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=311845053213&s=review-rank'}]

amazonPage = [{'title': '100% Non-GMO Berberine HCL Complex Supplement - Supports Gut, Heart, and Immune System Health- Harvested in The Himalayas, Helps Regulate Blood Sugar & Cholesterol, 100% Free of Additives & Allergens', 'price': '$14.95', 'image': 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/W/IMAGERENDERING_521856-T2/images/I/81D1P4QqLfL._AC_SX425_.jpg', 'rank': 'Best Sellers Rank: #194,130 in Health & Household (See Top 100 in Health & Household)\n#6,896 in Blended Vitamin & Mineral Supplements', 'rating': '4.7 out of 5'}, {'title': "Doctor's Best High Absorption CoQ10 with BioPerine, Vegan, Gluten Free, Naturally Fermented, Heart Health & Energy Production, 100 mg 60 Veggie Caps", 'price': '$14.24 ($0.24 / Count)', 'image': 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/W/IMAGERENDERING_521856-T2/images/I/71sNP5u1N1S._AC_SX425_.jpg', 'rank': 'Rank not found', 'rating': 'Rating not found'}, {'title': "Doctor's Best CoQ10 Gummies 200 Mg, Coenzyme Q10 (Ubiquinone), Supports Heart Health, Boost Cellular Energy, Potent Antioxidant, 60 Ct (Packaging May Vary)", 'price': '$19.96 ($0.33 / Count)', 'image': 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/W/IMAGERENDERING_521856-T2/images/I/71NIwP2V2uL._AC_SY450_.jpg', 'rank': 'Best Sellers Rank: #20,634 in Health & Household (See Top 100 in Health & Household)\n#73 in CoQ10 Nutritional Supplements', 'rating': '4.7 out of 5'}, {'title': 'CoQ10 300mg Doctors Best 30 Softgel', 'price': '$19.64', 'image': 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/W/IMAGERENDERING_521856-T2/images/I/61DttvOf18L._AC_SX425_.jpg', 'rank': 'Manufacturer \u200f : \u200e Doctors Best', 'rating': 'Rating not found'}, {'title': 'Ultra Glandulars Ultra Raw Eye 60 Tab', 'price': '$19.65', 'image': 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/W/IMAGERENDERING_521856-T2/images/I/71ASBPlEphL._AC_SX425_.jpg', 'rank': 
'Best Sellers Rank: #286,790 in Health & Household (See Top 100 in Health & Household)\n#14,261 in Herbal Supplements', 'rating': '4.1 out of 5'}, {'title': 'Mason Natural Garlic Oil 500 mg Odorless Allium Sativum Supplement - Supports Healthy Circulatory Function, 100 Softgels', 'price': '$6.75', 'image': 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/W/IMAGERENDERING_521856-T2/images/I/71eXVu3zxFL._AC_SX425_.jpg', 'rank': 'Best Sellers Rank: #346,287 in Health & Household (See Top 100 in Health & Household)\n#350 in Garlic Herbal Supplements', 'rating': '4.9 out of 5'}]



result = []
amazonPage.extend(amazondata)
for myDict in amazonPage:
    if myDict not in result:
        result.append(myDict)
print (result)

amazonPage[0].update(amazondata[0])

keys = amazonPage[0].keys()
print(keys)

with open('Test WF.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(result)
```

[csv output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHrOp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only merging the first dictionary in each list. You should merge them all.

```
result = [data | page for data, page in zip(amazondata, amazonPage)]
keys = result[0].keys()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Second time in less than 24 hours that you help me. Correcting I had to change the "+" operator to "|" because I was getting the error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'". Now it's working

Comment: Right, I was thinking of lists, not dictionaries.